# Refresh DATA VIEWER without Delete and put another one?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, union-all

After editing my union all components in my data viewer don't refresh and should delete and put another one to show what is edited I don't want to delete the first one data viewer and put another one because it is not good for the big project and take time. Is that any way that I could fix this bug?

This is a first step that I use DataViewer before edit my Union All.

[image: This Is A First Step That I Use DataViewr Before Edite my Union ALl]

This IS after editing the `UNION ALL`

[image: This IS AFter editing the Union ALL]
[[image: This is what I expect to see]]
But I've tested it a few times and found that if we change the name of Union All Component in the process of Editing, it will be OK and don't need to delete the data viewer.

Do you think there is a problem with the data viewer or the Union All component?

Comment: I don't really follow, but are you saying you're editing the package while it's running? That won't have any effect, the package has been built and is running the built version.

Comment: @Larnu Look, I have two databases that I want to use with the Union All components, so I want to overlay these two information using a Union All.according to the first pictures my data viewer shows me the information that not yet edited.
But when I edit Union All and run the package again, the Dataviwer shows me the information that was first shown, and in fact, does not refresh.
My question is what should I do for this problem? Without deleting the DataViewer and put another one

Comment: What do you mean the data that is not yet edited? None of your data is "edited", there's no transformations prior to the Union All. A Union All simply merges 2 identically defined datasets into one; it doesn't change the values of the individual rows in any way.

Comment: @Larnu I mean Edit
Union All input 1 and Union All input 2
I mean adding the city and synchronizing the country with the Keshvar columns
 please attention to the pictures

Comment: But you're pictures show the underlying data has changed and you changed the name of the Union All Tranformation. That's all.

Comment: @LarnuLook at the Union All transformation editor in 2 picture and compare to each other (that Edit I mean :))))

Comment: Ok, so that Union All Transformations have completely different definitions aswell, the columns change; one ignores the column "county" from the other set. I still; don't understand what you're asking here. Why would you not expect the data to change when you add the column "county"??

Comment: @Larnu Dude I really don't know how can explain my question for you that you can understand my question this is a very simple question 
look at the data Viewers and compare to each other
My problem is : after the edit Union all I run the package but still..... same information shows to me and don't refresh
how can fix this problem (without deleting my Data viewers)

Comment: But the data *has* changed in that image. That is my point. Country no longer has a value of `NULL` in some of the rows. So what is the problem? You haven't actually said what that is. You say the data "hasn't changed" and to "look at the images", but the data in the images *has* changed; so it doesn't convey what the problem is; and we don't have a description of what that "problem" is.

Comment: I wouldn't say they are being rude, @DaleBurrell, the OP is clearly frustrated, however, I do agree that they haven't really described the problem, hence the difficulty is working out the problem. A couple of images and a statement "look they aren't different" when they are doesn't tell a story. If they specifically tell us what they expect to be different, what isn't, then this sea of comments wouldn't be needed. :)

Comment: Rather than an image, it would be great if you described. Images don't always tell the full picture, and such large images reduced down to such a small size are difficult to compare.

Comment: Why would you *expect* the column City to still have values of `NULL`. You ***changed*** the defintion so that the column `KESHVAR` is displayed in the column `City`. I'm sorry, but I've asked enough times for you to **describe** the problem that I'm bored i'm being ignored. The reason your data is *different* is because the definition ***is*** different. You can't expect the result of something to *not* change if you change it's definition. That is one of the basics of data.

Comment: @Larnu I really know you're tired and apologize for taking your time
But that's not my problem with the concept of these changes
my problem is Data Viewer :))
I will Work on this case tomorrow and I really Tired Too :)

Answer (score 1):

A Union All transformation is an asynchronous component.

What that means is for each row of data that flows into it, there might be 0, 1 or many rows emitted. It also means that columns before the component have no relationship to columns after it. You might have `EmployeeID` fed into the component and an `EmployeeID` coming out of it but there is no guarantee they are the same entity. Behind the scenes, columns are assigned IDs and the names are just developer friendly concepts.

So when you add a new column to the source, the data viewer won't "know" about it because those columns aren't mapped coming out of the union all. When you rename them in the source, the Union All component should continue to work but the name change won't be sent to the downstream consumers because Column 73 which had a friendly name of `EmployeeID` is now just `Employee` in the source systems but the components downstream from Union All only know about column 129 which is *their* `Employee`. Since the data viewer is sitting downstream from the async component, you have to "fix it" whenever you make a material change to the data flow.

Specific to the example you have shown, two queries "union all"ed from the same database instance - don't do it like that. Async components, besides causing all the development headaches I have outlined above don't perform well. Instead, write your query with the Union All in the OLE DB Source component.

If you have a reason for creating the data flow as such, then sure, go for it. But if the data is coming from two databases on the same server, I can't think of a good reason to take the approach you have started down.